# select the rows based on unique column of each group from the table

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, mysql-5.7

```
----------------
c_id  s_id   p_id    (customer_id, service_id, provider_id)
---- ---- ------  
1,     1,     1 - not elegible to select as next entry has same p_id
1,     2,     1
1,     3,     3

2,     1,     1
2,     2,     2
2,     3,     3

3,     1,     3 - not elegible to select as next entry has same p_id
3,     2,     3 - not elegible to select as next entry has same p_id
3,     3,     3
```

What is the cost effective way of writing the query to produce below result from above data ?

```
 ----------------
 c_id  s_id  p_id 
 ---- ---- ------ 
  1,    2,   1
  1,    3,   3

  2,    1,   1
  2,    2,   2
  2,    3,   3

  3,    3,   3
```

Comment: mysql 5.7.23  @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: *not elegible to select as next entry has same p_id* The term "next" makes sense only after specifying the sorting order. Does ORDER BY s_id within the same c_id is safe ordering? Does s_id contains natural numbers from 1 and without skipped values for each separate c_id? Does it is possible that some c_id have p_id values like 1,2,1,1?

Comment: @Akina I can add new column `timestamp` to each row to sort p_id based on timestamp and select latest common p_id.

Comment: Show us some ways and we'll pick the most cost effective.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL 8.0, you can use `lead()` to retrieve the "next" `p_id`, and use that information to filter out rows whose `pid` is the same as the next value.

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lead(p_id) over(partition by c_id order by s_id) lead_p_id
    from mytable t
) t
where not p_id <=> lead_p_id
```

In earlier versions, you would typically use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where not pid <=> (
    select p_id
    from mytable t1
    where t1.c_id = t.c_id and t1.s_id > t.s_id
    order by t1.s_id
    limit 1
)
```

Comment: @Akina: Thanks. I added a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: Assume `p_id` for some `c_id` is 1,2,1,1... 1st row will be lost.

Comment: @Akina: I don't think so (if I understand correctly what you mean). Both queries consistently use `s_id` to sort rows having the same `p_id`.

Comment: yes he's right @Akina . Have a look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1db6b2b80dbf3ee8c443c0653fe997bc) . Congrats GMB, such a wonderful solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this is the most cost effective, but it def seems to be the most obvious solution I could think of.

```
select 
   c_id
   ,max(s_id) [s_id]
   ,p_id
from
  `table_name`
group by
   c_id
   ,p_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If `s_id` is a sequence with no gaps, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t left join
     t tnext
     on tnext.c_id = t.c_id and tnext.s_id = t.sid + 1
where not (tnext.p_id <=> t.p_id);
```